# Traversing a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C and now I am trying to learn the basics of linked list. The following code is only the segment of traversing a linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;
    start = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = start;
    start->next = NULL;


    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        list->item = i;
        printf("%p\t%p\n",start->next,list->next);
        list->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        list = list->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am confused that the output of "start->next" is not NULL, but a solid constant address. But I assigned NULL to start->next before the for loop, and only change the component in "list" (list->item and list->next), not the component in "start". So why component in "start" is changed?

Comment: Should be `printf("%p\t%p\n", (void *)start->next, (void *)list->next);`

Comment: It *was* NULL on the initial iteration, or didn't you notice that?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you have: `list = start`: They then both point to the same node, and as long as they are equal, `list->next` is the same as `start->next`.

On the `for` first iteration `start` and `list` are still equal and `start->next` will be NULL until you assign: `list->next = ...`.
After that first assignment, `start->next` will be modified to point at the malloced address.
On the next iterations `list` is pointing to other places and modifying `list->next` doesn't affect `start->next`.

---

Step by step: ("node X" are the names I give to the nodes allocated by malloc, they are not variables in your program)

```
node 0: { .item = ?, .next = NULL }  <---- start, list

i = 0;
list->item = i;

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = NULL }  <---- start, list

list->next = malloc(...)

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = &(node 1) }  <---- start, list
node 1: { .item = ?, .next = ?         }  <---- start->next, list->next

list = list->next

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = &(node 1) }  <---- start
node 1: { .item = ?, .next = ?         }  <---- start->next, list

i = 1;
list->item = i;

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = &(node 1) }  <---- start
node 1: { .item = 1, .next = ?         }  <---- start->next, list

list->next = malloc(...)

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = &(node 1) }  <---- start
node 1: { .item = 1, .next = &(node 2) }  <---- start->next, list
node 2: { .item = ?, .next = ?         }  <---- list->next

list = list->next;

node 0: { .item = 0, .next = &(node 1) }  <---- start
node 1: { .item = 1, .next = &(node 2) }  <---- start->next
node 2: { .item = ?, .next = ?         }  <---- list
```

etc.

Comment: "**_On the next iterations list is pointing to other places and modifying list->next doesn't affect start->next._**" . Can you please elaborate on this ? Does this suggest that linked_list in discontinued after that ?

Comment: @ameyCU, I added a step-by-step description to the answer - I hope the idea & notation are clear

Comment: Thanks for taking that trouble but what I asked was does the above line imply that `start->next->next` would be different from `list->next->next` ?

Comment: When? It depends on where the code is, because it changes where `list` is pointing at. Since your code changes `list` to iteratively point at the `->next` of each node, it will only be pointing at the same place as `start` during the beginning of the first iteration (until you do `list = list->next`)

Answer (score 2):

This is because if this assignment-

```
 list = start;
```

`list` points to same address to which `start` points to, so changes made at that location are same to both pointers (as they point to same memory location).

It is same as this example (*maybe more simple as code*)-

```
int a;
int *p1,*p2;
p1=&a;
p2=p1;
*p1=5;
prinf("value : p1=%d p2=%d",*p1, *p2 ); 
/* Both the pointer will have same value  as change is made at memory location */
```